# Can't open sys/bus/pci/device/ directory

Tags: c, linux, pci-bus

I am trying to read the resource file for my device and `mmap` it to read the device registers but when i try open the file location error prompts : **NO such file or directory**. I have changed the permissions of the file using chmod 666. The code I am using to open the file :

```
sprintf(filePath , "sys/bus/pci/devices/%04x:%02x:%02x.%d/resource0",segment,bus,device,function)

fileHandle = open(filePath , O_RDONLY);

if (fileHandle < 0)
{
    perror("ERRRO : ");
}
```

The file exists and I am able to read it using the cat utility.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to open a relative path (which does not exist):

```
sys/bus/pci/devices/%04x:%02x:%02x.%d/resource0
```

instead of an absolute one:

```
/sys/bus/pci/devices/%04x:%02x:%02x.%d/resource0
```